# Current flowing through a square loop - Magnetic Field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

> *A square conducting loop of wire of side $2a$ carries a uniform current I. Calculate the magnetic field at the centre of square due to the current in the loop.*